# Partitioning a Map in Java 8+

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, String>` and a `List<String>`. I'd like to partition the `Map` based on the condition

```
foreach(map.key -> list.contains(map.key))
```

and produce two `Map`(s). What's the most elegant way to do so? I'm on Java 11, so you can throw everything you want in the answers.

What I came up to for now is:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(partitioningBy(e -> list.contains(o.getKey())));
```

but that gives a `Map<Boolean, List<Entry<String, String>>>`.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993604/whats-the-purpose-of-partitioningby

Comment: Could you give an example with real data what you want to achieve? And I wouldnt necessarily go full stream here: a stream creates ONE result, but you want TWO maps?!

Comment: See related  stackoverflow.com/questions/28856781 . The best approach depends on the sizes of the Map and the list, and how the result should be used. As an example Guava Maps can simply and quickly provide 2 filtered views on the original map to avoid additional memory usage, but may have very bad performance if contains() is called a lot on the results.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can reduce each group using `toMap` (as a downstream collector):

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("d", "D");
myMap.put("c", "C");
myMap.put("b", "B");
myMap.put("A", "A");

List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

Map<Boolean, Map<String, String>> result = myMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                            entry -> myList.contains(entry.getKey()),
                            Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)
                    )
        );
```

And for this example, that produces `{false={A=A, d=D}, true={b=B, c=C}}`

Answer (score 9):

Though `partitioningBy` is the way to go when you need both the alternatives as an output based on the condition. Yet, another way out (useful for creating map based on a single condition) is to use `Collectors.filtering` as :

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of("d", "D","c", "C","b", "B","A", "A");
List<String> myList = List.of("a", "b", "c");
Predicate<String> condition = myList::contains;

Map<String, String> keysPresentInList = myMap.keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.filtering(condition,
                Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get)));
Map<String, String> keysNotPresentInList = myMap.keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.filtering(Predicate.not(condition),
                Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get)));
```

or alternatively, if you could update the existing map in-place, then you could retain entries based on their key's presence in the list using just a one-liner:

```
myMap.keySet().retainAll(myList);
```

Comment: I guess using stream().filter( ... ).collect( ... ) would be the same ?

Comment: @Asoub indeed. suggested by Darshan's answer here.

Answer (score 7):

You can have filtered `map` by applying filtering on the original `map`, e.g.:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //List of values
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, String> filteredMap = map.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(e -> list.contains(e.getKey()))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

You can then compare the `filteredMap` contents with original `map` to extract the entries that are not present in the `filteredMap`.

Comment: This approach has horrible performance O(n * m), when for HashMaps and input, given get() and contains() have O(1), a solution of O(m) is possible. See stackoverflow.com/questions/28856781

Answer (score 6):

You can't really produce two separate maps using streams (at least not in the most elegant way). Don't be afraid to use the old regular `forEach`, I think it's quite a clean version:

```
Map<String, String> contains = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> containsNot = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
    if (yourList.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        contains.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    } else {
        containsNot.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could iterate the map and use the goodies introduced in Java 8+:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<String, String>> result = Map.of(true, new LinkedHashMap<>(), 
                                                  false, new LinkedHashMap<>());
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
map.forEach((k, v) -> result.get(set.contains(k)).put(k, v));
```

First, we create a `result` map with two entries, one for each partition. The values are `LinkedHashMap`s so that insertion order is preserved.

Then, we create a `HashSet` from the list, so that invoking `set.contains(k)` is a `O(1)` operation (otherwise, if we did `list.contains(k)`, this would be `O(n)` for each entry of the map, thus yielding a total time complexity of `O(n^2)`, which is bad).

Finally, we iterate the input map and put the `(k, v)` entry in the corresponding partition, as per the result of invoking `set.contains(k)`.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to @ernest_k 's answer you can use a function and `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("d", "D");
myMap.put("c", "C");
myMap.put("b", "B");
myMap.put("A", "A");
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

Function<Entry<String, String> , Boolean> myCondition =  i -> myList.contains(i.getKey());

Map<Boolean,List<Entry<String, String>>>  myPartedMap = myMap.entrySet()
        .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myCondition));

System.out.println(myPartedMap);
```